# refresh vilolations drilldown after violation severity is changed

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I performed sonar checks `mvn sonar:sonar` and after I realised that some violations have too high severity. So I updated their severity in quality profile.

However existing violations are not updated, is it possible to update existing violations without running check (`mvn sonar:sonar`) again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you should run a new sonar analysis to use the new profile settings.
Keep in mind that once an analysis has been stored in Sonar DB, can't be changed. So in any case you need to run a new one.